# Sql group by working not properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

This is my query

```
select  
 (sum(case when offer1_delivered is not null then 1 else null end) ) as PenetrationRate1
,(sum(case when offer2_delivered is not null then 1 else null end)) as PenetrationRate2
,count(TargetMkgListID) as TargetMkgListID from tablename
```

## output

```
PenetrationRate1    PenetrationRate2    TargetMkgListID 
1                   2                3
```

I need to include customername column in this query

```
select  customername,
 (sum(case when offer1_delivered is not null then 1 else null end) ) as PenetrationRate1
,(sum(case when offer2_delivered is not null then 1 else null end)) as PenetrationRate2
,count(TargetMkgListID) as TargetMkgListID from tablename
group by customername
```

If I include customername in my query, groupby is not working properly.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  customername
,(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN offer1_delivered is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0)) AS PenetrationRate1
,(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN offer2_delivered is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0)) AS PenetrationRate2
,COUNT(TargetMkgListID) as TargetMkgListID from tablename
GROUP BY customername
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the ISNULLs? `CASE .. THEN 1 ELSE 0` cannot result in `NULL`. When you see that they're redundant, then how is this answer different to another one posted 30 minutes earlier?

Comment: If we are using **ELSE 0**  Instead of **Else NULL** we don't need ISNULL in the select statement

Comment: Exactly, so why did you add it?

Comment: Don't need either one... I works with just `case WHEN offer2_delivered is not null THEN 1 End`

Answer (score 1):

```
select  customername,
 (sum(case when offer1_delivered is not null then 1 else 0 end) ) as PenetrationRate1
,(sum(case when offer2_delivered is not null then 1 else 0 end)) as PenetrationRate2
,count(TargetMkgListID) as TargetMkgListID from tablename
group by customername
```

Comment: I am guessing by "not working" that you are seeing NULLs. If it's something else, please edit the question and add some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one customerName value in the table, Try

```
select Min(customername),
       sum(case when offer1_delivered is not null then 1 end) PenetrationRate1,
       sum(case when offer2_delivered is not null then 1 end) PenetrationRate2,
       count(TargetMkgListID) TargetMkgListID 
from tablename
```

If there is more than one customerName in the table, then you can't add customerName to Select clause and still get the sums of ALL the records in the table (only one row in output). You can only get the sum of the records by each customername, which is what your second query should be doing. So if that second query is not what you want then you have a problem because what you want is probably not logically possible with the data you have